# 'initialOpenedSections' Must be set before the tableview has started loading data

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have tableview which has multiple sections in my viewcontroller.
And I'd like to open all sections when viewcontroller appeared.
When I navigate to the viewcontroller at first, It works well.
But when I navigate to another viewcontroller and navigate back to this viewcontroller, I've got this error. 
'initialOpenedSections' Must be set before the tableview has started loading data.
I've set tableview.initialopensections in viewwillappear().
Please give me suggesstion if you have experienced.